# List the distinct principal ideals in $\mathbb{ℤ}_5 \times \mathbb{ℤ}_{12}$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

If I want to accomplish this, do I need to first list all the elements of $\mathbb{ℤ}_5 \times \mathbb{ℤ}_{12}$ and then multiply each individual pair by all other 48 pairs to see in the end the unique (distinct) pairs possible, or am I missing some trick that would allow a more efficient process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First note that $\mathbb Z_5$ is a field so if $(a, b)$ generates an ideal and $a \neq 0$ then $(a^{-1}, 1)$ is a unit so multiplying I get that $(1, b)$ generates the ideal as well.  So your generators are of the form $(0, b)$ or $(1, b)$.

Also note that the Chinese remainder theorem tells you that $\mathbb Z_{12} \simeq \mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_4$.  Since $\mathbb Z_3$ is also a field you can reduce your options even further.

Answer (score 1):

By CRT you have the cyclic ring $\Bbb Z_{60}$.  The principal ideals are all the ideals of the form $n\Bbb Z_{60}$, where $n|60$.